# Margin-right in safari on win and Mac

Tags: html, css, safari

HI my problem is why in Safari on Win margin-right is working but on Mac not? Its a bug or i have anything bad? Is any alternative how to resolve it?
my not working css

```
{
top:auto;
bottom:0px;
z-index:100;
margin:0 0 0 48%;
background-color:#fff;
background-image:url("../img/arr_up_blue.png");
-webkit-transition: .7s;
transition: .7s;
height:0;
border:0;
```

}

Comment: The Win version is outdated, so forget about that. You need to provide a proper, working example to get any coding help. CSS on its own is meaningless.

Comment: btw your margin-right is Zer0 in your css.. maybe you mean margin-left?

Comment: margin-left not working too :/